# How to send Verbose message to teamcity?

Tags: logging, teamcity

I would like to send message to teamcity that would be only visible when I select the "Verbose" view. (check [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Log))

[Here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-CommonProperties) is description of messages status, but it only has 4 states:

- NORMAL
- ERROR
- WARNING
- FAILURE

**Is there a way to send something like this to teamcity?**

```
##teamcity[message text='secret message' status='VERBOSE']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing with normal output.Verbose is same as NORMAL or just plain console output. You can also group "detailed view" into its own block.

Here's an example:

```
##teamcity[blockOpened name='Details']
Cleaning some files...
##teamcity[blockClosed name='Details']
```

I've been playing with blocks awhile ago, http://log.ld.si/post/build-log-in-teamcity-using-psake